# In Entity framework can we give our custom name of parameter say @x instead of autogenerated @p__linq__0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have below code

```
foreach (string search in searchValue){
                    searchValueParam = search;
                    queries.Add(from e in context.employee
                                where e.name == searchValueParam
                                select e);
                }

 int i= queries
                    .Sum(q => q.Count());
```

If I pass two values in searchValue array, the code generate expression with parameter  @p__linq__0 for both two queries and @p__linq__0 has the value of last element of searchValue array.

Is there a way I can create new parameter for individual query and each have its own value?

```
EF Generated code
    SELECT 
        [Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
        [Extent1].[employee_id] AS [employee_id]
        FROM [dbo].[employees] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[name] = @p__linq__0
```

Comment: Why would you need this? Do you have an actual use case for controlling the parameter name in a EF-generated query?

Comment: Need to known the sum of row count return by each query

Comment: They will be executed as separate queries anyway, so the parameter name really doesn't matter. Sounds like XY problem. Could you update your question with the real case you are trying to solve.

Comment: Have you tried doing `context.employee.Count(e => searchValue.Contains(e.name))`? It's would be more efficient to collapse all of this into one query.

Comment: searchValue have two values i.e. "V1" and "V2", I want to get the total count of rows exist for these two values. MY table have just one record for "V1". The code  'queries.Sum(q => q.Count());' should return me 1 but it says 0.

Comment: You can link EF to a stored proc and use that instead of having EF generate the select statement.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that `searchValueParam` is declared outside of the loop and will contain the last assigned value at the time queries are executed. Either remove it from outside and use `var searchValueParam = ...` inside the loop, or better use @p.s.w.g suggestion.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. Actually I was asked just to change one line to solve this issue. I just changed    `where e.name == searchValueParam`    to    `let x = name  where e.name.Contains(x)` which solves the problem